# Pandas remove character from string in column NOT containing substring

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove "-" in each cell of a column of a dataframe that does not contain "BC".
I do not know how to tweak the following code to "not containing" instead of "containing"
Any help is appreciated.

`slate['start'] = slate['start'].astype(str).str.findall('BC'.replace("-",""))`
This worked for the inverse case of: replace x with y if cell contains Z.

`slate['start'] = slate['start'].astype(str).str.findall(~'BC'.replace("-",""))`
I then added the tilde (in my frustration) which clearly did not fork for strings - it yielded a TypeError.
I do not know of any neat way to implement this.

My df is of this "style"

name    municipality    start   end ext x   y

0   La Coma Altafulla   -200 AD 125 AD  1.74    1.379991    41.154995

Comment: what's the `'start'` column format, is it always `<number>` followed by 2 uppercased letters?

Comment: Yes it is, it is <number> then "AD or "BC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), which replaces values where the condition (the first argument) is false with the values from the second argument:

```py
slate.start.where(slate.start.str.contains('BC'),
                  slate.start.str.replace('-', ''), 
                  inplace=True)
```